# How to add items to extjs panel after clearing it from previous items?

Tags: extjs

Hello I use this code to add label items to panel dynamically, but when clearing the items and trying to add new items again nothing happen:

```
var mText = new Ext.form.Label({});      
      mText.draggable="constrain: true; constrainTo: mSurface";      
      mSurface.add(mText);
      mSurface.doLayout();
      mText.on('move',function(t,x,y,eOpts){        
        MainForm.lbx.setText(x,false); 
        MainForm.lby.setText(y,false);                  
        obj.set('o_x',parseInt(x));
        obj.set('o_y',parseInt(y));
      });      
      mText.getEl().on('render', function(t,eOpts) {cur_obj=mText;});
      mText.getEl().on('click', function(e,t,eOpts) {cur_obj=mText;Tree_Select(mText.id);});
      mText.getEl().on('contextmenu', function(e,t,eOpts) {e.stopEvent();cur_obj=mText;mnutxtContext.showAt(e.getXY());});
```

The mSurface.removeAll() do nothing !! so I use this to clear the panel:

```
Ext.each(mSurface.items.items, function(cmp) 
 { 
  cmp.destroy();
  //mSurface.remove(cmp); //doesn't work also 
 });
```

I have read almost every thing in extjs 4.2 api and tried to google it but nothing, I think that removeAll should work, maybe the way I add the labels to the panel is wrong or there is something that I am missing...

Thank you for advice..:-)

Comment: This is not the way of coding in Ext. First, do not use keyword `new` but use `Ext.create`. Then, do not use imperative way (create empty label and then configure it), but do use declarative way: pass a config object to Ext.create. Then, you do not need to first create a component and then add it to a container but you can pass the config object directly to `add` method - Ext will create the component when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after struggling..:-(((((

I just change the config to:

```
var mText = new Ext.form.Label({id:obj.get('o_id')});
```

When I pass the 'id' in the config the 'removeAll' works fine!!! but when I set the 'id' after creating and adding the component to the panel the 'removeAll' doesn't work...

I really don't know why but I'll be happy to have an explanation for this behavior !